# spritekit, texture image sometime load sometimes not

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, sprite-kit

I have simple game that has some spritenode with images that I have in an asset catalog, is configured for ipad only and I have 2 versions of the images, one 1x and 2x, the thing is that the game was created in ios 8 and is was working perfect, now when I opened in xcode 7 with ios 9 it suggest me to convert the code to swift 2 which I did, the process told it need to change like 2 things, nothing big because the game is kinda simple.

The problem I have is when I start the game in the simulator or and ipad with ios 9 the images sometimes load at the beginning and then they just disappear  and sometimes they don't even appear at all, I had try to insert the images again but without any result, also I tried to create a new project also no result.

I have no idea why this is happening, please any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed, the problem was that the sprites were in different position and they were hidden by others, it appears that iOS 9 is forcing me to use zPosition on each sprite now, it wasn't necessary before, anyway doing that fix my issue, but I think is a bug

Comment: Setting the zPosition fixed it for me. Thanks !